# this in javascript constructor function

Tags: javascript, constructor

```
function Foo() {  
    alert(this === a);//return false!   **why this is not equal a?**  
}  
var a = new Foo();//create a new object
```

foo is a constructor,why this in the 'Foo' is not equal with 'a'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assignment to the variable `a` has not yet happened when you're inside the constructor.  The sequence of events is:

1. Create a new object
2. Run the constructor
3. Assign the new object to the variable `a`.

Comment: @KooiInc alerts true?i run the code in firebug, it alerts false.

Comment: @ray: run the exact code string I gave in my previous comment in whatever browser. My code string differs from yours - alert(this*.name* === a);.

Comment: @KooiInc - the only reason your code alerts `true` is because both `this.name` and `a` are `undefined`.  That isn't accomplishing anything.

Answer (score -1):

i think "this" referring to as a object, but "this.a" is true as that is the object

Comment: There is no `this.a` here.  So i don't really get what you're trying to say.

Comment: well it look to me as being as ray was trying to check for equality on "a" as "this" was an object of objects